# How to relate branch to GitLab "Task" (not to Issue)?

Tags: gitlab, issue-tracking

Using all the default settings, without any special customization, I create an Issue, then in [Child items] I click on [Add] button and pick [New task]. (Those tasks got an Id number similar to Issues, from the **same** incremented sequence)

If I query the Issues in my project, (Plan/Issues menu) those child items 'Tasks' are together with my 'Issues' together in a *flattened list, but their icons are different*.

**Question:**

For the Issues I have [Create merge request] button and its sub options, however for the Task no such thing. How can I relate a branch to this Task?

**What I have tried so far:**

I've tried to manually create a branch and use the GitLab convention in the name `idnumber-name` but this did not make the branch appear in the Task under [Related branches], actually there is no [Related branches] section as there is no related branch.